# Downgrade Android SDK from 29 to 21

Tags: android, api, gradle, sdk

I need to downgrade my SDK to 21 in order to test some deprecated features that are no longer working properly on SDK 29. But when I lower SDK and sync project it gives an error when compiling app.

The error is `C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\93bc303e0edf41378a70a682ebb74605\appcompat-1.1.0\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.`

Here are my build.gradle settings

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.oldstuff"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

What should be added/removed?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you use **compileSdkVersion** and **buildToolsVersion** less than **26**

Your **compileSdkVersion** is 21, but it can be possible that third party libraries use resources that were only added in API 26 or later. Either update your **build.gradle** file to use the newest **compileSdkVersion** or try to **downgrade** third party libraries.

Comment: Think that I need to downgrade libraries. Can you tell me please how to choose correct libraries? Or which ones are compatible with SDK 21?